# Hazardous Chemicals Waste Recycling company & KOH production, ABANDONED the site

Tags: environmental-engineering

A Hazardous Chemicals Waste Recycling company & KOH production, ABANDONED the site, they cut (looks like with a diamond saw) the concrete floor (25cm height) at about the middle of the warehouse, in the size/shape of a bed, for what reasons?  and, some Circular Cuttings (diameter of a round plate)?

What would be the PURPOSE of ALL these CUTTINGS?

They also did cuttings on the asphalt floor outside the building, rectangular shape (approx 400m2 & 300m2 area), and replaced it with NEW ASPHALT. Few months after they left the site, the NEW ASPHALT is covered with rusty powder. How is the RUSTY powder forming? chemical reaction??

There is also BLACK OIL forming above the OLD asphalt floor? How come it's rising from the floor? chemical reaction??

Comment: It sounds like they were taking samples for contamination testing. What exactly is *your* interest in the site?

Comment: Thanks for your reply & inspection was done (TPH,VOC/SVOC,ICP,pH) & the specialists are corrupt!!! It's a long story... My father passed away last year, and I'm left with a very contaminated & corroded property, and I cannot prove it!!! I just wanted a GENERAL understanding of what's going on. Can you pls help?

Comment: It sounds like you need some very specialist technical help in order to determine what the contaminants are, and some very specialist legal help in order to protect your interests. SE is not the place to get it. Where in the world are you, anyway?

Comment: Dave, I'm couple of hours away from you. And, the lawyers (top law firm) are also corrupt!!!  I just wanted a GENERAL understanding of what's going on with the site? Thanks

Comment: You should at least try to ask separate questions. You'll find that many questions should be asked elsewhere, E. G the chemistry stack exchange site. But you will obviously have to have well constructed questions requiring you to have done background reading. Your better option might be to find a forum specialising in matters relating to site contamination.  There must also be independent regulatory bodies that you can ask for info on practices, requirements etc. I have both up voted your question  and voted to close it, as it is not a suitable format for stack exchange but is a fair question.

Comment: This question is very broad.  It's hard to understand what *specifically* you are asking.  Location is also going to be very relevant.  Without a good idea of location, some pictures, and a clear description of what you are really asking, this isn't a valid question for this site.